# import failure for Admob library on Eclipse for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I am trying place a banner ad from Admobs on my Android app and I receive the following error when I run my program

"com.google.ads.AdView failed to instantiate."

The program installs on the emulator and functions properly but because of this error my banner never displays. I've tried importing the library through both of these lines (not simultaneously).

```
import com.google.ads.*;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
```

Yet I continue to get the instantiation failure... Any advice? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Hey thanks. I ended up reloading the JAR file and I also had some problems in my android manifest.

Comment: I wonder how I close a question down... or say I found my own answer..

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning your project, often times files get messed up when its building automatically.